# Typescript Transform json const to interface type

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I want to transform the following const json:

```
export const iconRegistry = {
  home: {
    ciclogoc: 'cic-c',
    ciclogoi: 'cic-i',
    ciclogont: 'cic-nt'
  },
};
```

to this interface type:

```
export interface IconDescription {
key: string;
value: string;
icon?: string;
}
```

So home should be key, value should be ciclogoc and icon should be cic-c.

This is what I have now but it is not working correctly:

```
public getIcons(): IconDescription[] {
    let result: IconDescription[] = [];
    for (let key in iconRegistry) {
        result = _.map(iconRegistry, item => {
            let icons: IconDescription[] = [];
            for (let value in item) {
                console.log('KEY:', key, 'VALUE:', value, 'ICON:', item[value]);
                icons.push({ key, value, icon: item[value] });
            }
            return icons;
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some help I got it finally right. I iterate over all the icons and then again over all values and push them to IconDescription.

```
  public getIcon(): IconDescription[] {
    for (let key in iconRegistry) {
        for (let value in iconRegistry[key]) {
            this.icons.push({ key, value, icon: iconRegistry[key][value] });
        }
    }
      return this.icons;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop twice through your iconRegistry:

```js
public getIcons(): IconDescription[] {
    let result: IconDescription[] = [];
    for (let key in iconRegistry) { // loop 1
        result = _.map(iconRegistry, item => { // loop 2
            let icons: IconDescription[] = [];
            for (let value in item) {
                console.log('KEY:', key, 'VALUE:', value, 'ICON:', item[value]);
                icons.push({ key, value, icon: item[value] });
            }
            return icons;
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've rewritten your code (is not tested)

```js
public getIcons(): IconDescription[] {
    let result: IconDescription[] = [];
    for (let key in iconRegistry) { //loop through the iconRegistry
        for (let icon in key) { // loop thourgh the icons under the key
            // fill the icon object and add it to the result set
            let icon: IconDescription = {}; 
            icon.key = key;
            icon.value = icon;
            icon.icon = key[icon];
            result.push(icon);
        }        
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: to fix your code you should change _.map(iconRegistry with _.map(iconRegistry[key]